# What does typedef with no type mean?

Tags: c, typedef

From the Standard [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.8:

> A `typedef` declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym
>   for the type so specified.

So I expected that it is not possible to write something like this:

```
typedef t;
t *t_ptr;
```

and it should fail to compile since no type to introduce a synonym to provided. But it is fine: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Gf8NMM). So what does this ever mean and why does it compile?

Comment: It is as fine as MSVC is a fine C compiler, i.e. not fine at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This relies on the fact that, missing type specification defaults to `int`.

So, your statement

```
 typedef t;
```

is the same as

```
 typedef int t;
```

With the proper level of warning, compiler emits warning:

```
warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘t’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 typedef t;
         ^
```

That said, **do not** rely on this behaviour, "implicit int" rule has been obsolete since `C99`.

Comment: So reasonable to ask if it is Standardized?

Comment: @SomeName it was, 3 decades ago and has not been for 2 decades.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala So now the behavior is undefined or implementation defined?

Comment: @SomeName neither. A C99, C11, C17 compiler **must** diagnose this as an incorrect program.

Comment: @SomeName The support itself for implicit int is removed, though it is still provided as compiler extension. Use strict mode , and your code should **fail to compile** in first place.

Answer (score 3):

It defaults to an `int`.

The compiler warning shows what is going on:

```
#1 with x86-64 gcc 8.2
<source>:1:9: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 't' [-Wimplicit-int]
 typedef t;
```

From **C99** onwards, the *implicit* `int` rule was removed. So this is not applicable from C99  onward.

If you use the **`-pedantic-errors`** compiler option in GCC (meaning strict conformity to the standard), **it issues an error**. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Qs-cPb).

If you are interested, the [relevant section](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.2) in **C89** standard which allowed this:

> **3.5.2 Type specifiers**
>   Each list of type specifiers shall be one of the following sets; the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.
>
> - void
> - char
> - signed char
> - unsigned char
> - short , signed short , short int , or signed short int
> - unsigned short , or unsigned short int
> - **int , signed , signed int , or no type specifiers**

So in **C99**, the last part of what was bolded above (**or no type specifiers**) was removed.

Comment: Please don't confuse readers by quoting now-outdated `C89`, not everyone may know about the applicability of the standards. :)

Comment: I did mention that it is not relevant from C99 onwards. But I can make it extra clear.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you move the positioning of the two blocks. **First**, mention about C99/C11 and then, about C89. Just my two cents.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Done.

Answer (score 0):

A `typedef` declaration defines a synonym for an object or pointer type. So you should specify both the type for which you want to create a synonym, and a name to use as synonym.

For example:

```
// 'byte_t' is a synonym for 'unsigned char'
typedef unsigned char byte_t;
// 'handler_t' is a synonym for 'void (*)(int)', a function pointer
typedef void (*handler_t)(int);
// 'short_p' is a synonym for 'short *'
typedef short * short_p;
// 'record' is a synonym for an anonymous structure
typedef struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
    } record;
// 'error_p' is a synonym for a pointer to 'struct error', defined somewhere else
typedef struct error *error_p;
```

Many more examples in the source you cited.

Comment: This is fine, but how does this answers the question?

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh I felt that the `typedef` syntax was new to him, so I give him some basic examples with comments. Other answers already addressed the compilation problem in itself.

Comment: Please don't invent your own terms and grammar that don't even exist in the C language. There are no syntax items called "base-type" or "type-alias".

Comment: @Lundin. Thanks. I should have specified that `base-type` and `type-alias` should have been replaced by actual types and names. Moreover that pseudo-syntax didn't suit function types. I also changed `alias` to `synonym`, since the C standards refers to typedef names as such.